# Async Queries not working right in Spring Data JPA project

Tags: java, jpa, asynchronous, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

After going through @KevinBowersox's Infinite Skills course on Spring Data for Java Developers, the only part that didn't seem to work as advertised were the Async methods. Mind you, at the beginning of the course he covered xml and Java configuration, but he proceeded to use the xml configuration throughout the rest of the course, whereas, I kept using Java configuration for each of the exercises and was able to get all the other parts to work. One minor difference is I am using IntelliJ IDEA rather than STS, as he uses throughout the course.

If anyone familiar with Spring Data Async Queries or the segment of his course (https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/spring-data-for/9781771375924/video241705.html) has some insight into what might be missing, please let me know.

Here are the relevant bits:

/* Application.java */

```
@EnableAsync
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            DataConfiguration.class)) {
        BookRepository repository = context.getBean(BookRepository.class);

        // TODO: Make method Async
        for (long x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            repository.findByIds(x);
        }
    }
}
```

}

/* BaseRepository.java */

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    @Override
    @Async("executor")
    List<T> findByIds(ID... ids);
}
```

/* ExtendedRepositoryImpl.java */

```
public class ExtendedRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {
    private JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation;
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public ExtendedRepositoryImpl(
            JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation,
            EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findByIds(ID... ids) {
        Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery("select e from " + this.entityInformation.getEntityName()
        + " e where e." + this.entityInformation.getIdAttribute().getName() + " in :ids");
        query.setParameter("ids", Arrays.asList(ids));

        long wait = new Random().nextInt(10000-1) +1;
        System.out.println(wait);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Executing query for ID: " + Arrays.toString(ids));

        return (List<T>) query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

/* DataConfiguration.java (aka AppConfig.java) */

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
            basePackages = {"com.infiniteskills.springdata.async"},
            repositoryBaseClass = com.infiniteskills.springdata.async.data.repository.ExtendedRepositoryImpl.class,
            repositoryImplementationPostfix = "CustomImpl")
    @EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "customAuditorAware")
    @EnableAsync
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan("com.infiniteskills.springdata.async")
    @Configuration
    public class DataConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {
        @Bean
        public CustomAuditorAware customAuditorAware() {
            return new CustomAuditorAware();
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
            return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
        }

        @Bean
        public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            // Generate tables in database
            vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

            Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
            //jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
            //jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");

            // After DDL has been run, run init script to populate table with data.
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "init.sql");

            // Entity Manager Factory Bean
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.infiniteskills.springdata.async");
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
            return entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
            return transactionManager;
        }

        @Override
        @Bean(name = "executor")
        public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
            executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
            executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
            executor.setThreadNamePrefix("executor-");
            executor.initialize();
            return executor;
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you telling whether it is async or not?

Comment: @Scary-Wombat The output of the course video stacks the generated time delays in console output immediately. The course's video executes the numbered threads based on lesser wait duration to greater wait duration (reflected in console). My console output displays timestamps that indicate that each execution is sequentially waiting the entire wait duration of each (in order) before executing. No indication of async execution for lesser wait durations prior to greater wait durations.

Answer (score 1):

The method has to have return type `void` or `Future` in order to be called asynchronous.

You can read up on it in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async

Comment: I find it odd that @kevin-bowersox never mentions this in his course, and yet his solution ostensibly works fine... His code was returning a List<String> and was casting, so the compiler balks if you attempt to cast something to a Future<List<String>> or FutureCompletable<List<String>>. It, didn't however seem necessary to return anything, so I modified the method's signature to a void return type and now am getting an  error creating the transactionManager bean instead, so I'm not yet sure if there are many more issues than meet the eye.

Answer (score 1):

`@EnableAsync` is used on any of your `@Configuration` classes.

From the [`docs`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html)

> To be used together with @Configuration classes as follows, enabling annotation-driven async processing for an entire Spring application context:

So annotate your `Application` class with `@Configuration`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added the `@Configuration` annotation to the `Application` class, but it still appears to be executing sequentially, rather than asynchronously (as indicated by the timestamps).

Comment: `2017-07-20 10:36:21 INFO LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:379 - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' `

`2793 Executing query for ID: [0] 2017-07-20 10:36:24 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as ...`

`3339 Executing query for ID: [1] 2017-07-20 10:36:27 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as ...`

`8704 Executing query for ID: [2] 2017-07-20 10:36:36 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as ...`

`1613 Executing query for ID: [3] 2017-07-20 10:36:37 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as ...`

Comment: Probably [this](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/how-to-execute-asynchronous-query-with-spring-jpa-and-postgresql-spring-boot) can help you

Comment: [This](http://memorynotfound.com/asynchronous-service-with-spring-async-and-java-future/) also helped... Ostensibly using try-with-resources does not play nice with async. That was what was sabotaging me the entire time... Ugh.

Comment: Huh?, that page doesn't even contain the word "try"

Answer (score 0):

Since I kept using Java configuration in the exercise, I initially wasn't sure if I was using all the correct annotations equivalent to the demonstrated xml configuration. And IntelliJ IDEA can render differing code suggestions than STS...

Anyway, the Spring Data Async Queries segment of the course (https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/spring-data-for/9781771375924/video241705.html) made me question my sanity.

Basically, it turns out my `Application.java` class:

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            DataConfiguration.class)) {
        BookRepository repository = context.getBean(BookRepository.class);

        // TODO: Make method Async
        for (long x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            repository.findByIds(x);
        }
    }
}
```

}

should have done without the `try-with-resources` syntax and instead looked like this:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            DataConfiguration.class)
        BookRepository repository = context.getBean(BookRepository.class;

        for (long x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            repository.findByIds(x);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the problem?

Comment: 1. Returning void or Future type didn't solve the problem. 2. Adding the @Configuration tag to the Application class didn't solve the problem. 3. Removing the try-with-resources syntax enabled the asynch queries to run and complete asynchronously.

Comment: If this is really the case, please open a bug against the Spring framework.

Comment: @JensSchauder, are you/ have you been able to get asynch queries to run inside try-with-resources blocks?

Comment: I used async only with Java 6, but try-with-resources is just syntactic sugar, and I don't see how or why this should keep them from working.